# Camera2 CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL

Tags: android, camera2

I want to capture pictures through `Camera2 API`, and I need to control the exposure time. But when I set `CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL` or just set the exposure time, I get black picture. When I cancel the setting, I can get the right picture again.

**The following is my setting code.**

```
// if the phone's level is full or other which can control mannually
mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, exposureValue);
mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, isoValue);
mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION,valueFrame);

//exposureValue and isoValue and valueFrame is valid.

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onConfigured: startPreview");
                        mPreviewCaptureSession = session;
                        try {
                            mPreviewCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                                    null, mBackgroundHandler); 
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onConfigureFailed: startPreview");

                    }
                }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After setting like above, when I capture a picture or save the preview frame, I can just get a black picture. But when I cancel the manual setting, I can save the picture.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: What kinds of values are you using for exposure time, sensitivity, and frame duration?

Comment: @EddyTalvala  I set the exposuretime to 100us，exposure time to 1600 and frame duration to 30. My phone supports them all. And I have solved the problem just now. I change the image Format to YVV_420_888, and convert it to the bitmap ,then save it. Now I can get the picture. But I don'know why.

Comment: What format were you using before? 100 us is pretty short (I assume you entered it as 100000, since the exposure time is in nanoseconds), so in indoor lighting you may well get a very dark image.  I'd recommend something like 1-10ms as an initial test value, or connect it to a slider so you can easily figure out if this is just a too-small exposure value.

Comment: @EddyTalvala I have tried to connect it to slider controlling my exposure time , the preview is normal, and before I change  the image format to YUV, imageReader can get the bytes, but can not write it to the file.

Comment: Again, what format were you using before switching to YUV?

Comment: @EddyTalvala JPEG